# Symbolically expressing a certain statement

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I wish to write

> Let $S$ be a nonempty set and let $T$ be a collection of subsets of $S$. If $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ for all pairs $A,B$ of elements of $T$, then there exists an element $x \in S$ such that $x \in C$ for all $C \in T$

symbolically. My attempt is as follows:

Let $S \neq \emptyset, T = \{ S_1,S_2,\dots,S_n \} \ni S_i \subseteq S.$ For $\forall (i,j) \in \{ (i,j) \in \mathbb{Z} : 1 \le i,j,\le n \land i \neq j \}, S_i \cap S_j \neq \emptyset \implies \exists x \in S, \forall C \in T, x \in C.$

I hope that I did it correctly. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Maybe you can use the fact that $T$ is a subset of power-set $\mathcal P(S)$

Comment: And you have to specify that $S \ne \emptyset$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's a good idea, so I could definitely more appealing, but is it correct as it is now?

Comment: How can you define $n$? Collection $T$ is whatever: it may be infinite, it may be empty...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think by assumption T is finite, because my book deals with only finite sets for now.

Comment: The "for" is not needed. $\forall$ itself means "for all".

Comment: I would suggest: $[S≠∅ \land \forall X (X \in T \to X⊆S) \to ∀A,B [( A \in T \land B \in T \land A \cap B \ne \emptyset) \to ∃x∈S∀C (C ∈ T \to x∈C)]]$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see, thanks.